# Cassandra sudden errors Mutation of x bytes is too large

Tags: database, cassandra, scalability

After some weeks of stress tests with a Cassandra 3.10 cluster, suddenly errors ["Mutation of x bytes is too large"](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/207267063-Mutation-of-x-bytes-is-too-large-for-the-maxiumum-size-of-y-?mobile_site=true) have appeared, with high CPU load (e.g. `load average: 33.26, 32.47, 32.15`) on all the 6 nodes.

There has been not change in the size of the executed queries, so we have tried to increase the `commit_log_segment_size_in_mb` . It doesn't help much. The result of `nodetool info` is as bellows.

```
Gossip active          : true
Thrift active          : false
Native Transport active: true
Load                   : 126.04 GiB
Generation No          : 1498838154
Uptime (seconds)       : 68795
Heap Memory (MB)       : 3258.00 / 8004.00
Off Heap Memory (MB)   : 597.23
```

Some `blob` are inserted, with predictable max size (and unchanged by the degradation time) or ~18kb (avg ~10kb).

Data are mainly updated using single-partition atomic/logged batches (with configurable and so preditable max batch size), as it was providing the best throughput according the stress tests.
Note that even if reverting now to individual async update doesn't fix this degradation.

What could have caused this sudden degradation of the performances ?

The amount of data had increased (~ * 1.1), but I would not expect it to cause such disproportionate issue (there is no lack of available disk storage related to that). I would expect Cassandra to scale well in such situation.

Thanks for ideas

Comment: Are you inserting huge blobs? Whats your load?

Comment: There is no change about either the avg size of column values or the used queries to write them